# FixedSys looks different under Japanese locale?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

In Windows 7 in C:\Windows\Fonts, this is what FixedSys looks like when my system is set to English (US) locale:

[image]

And this is what it looks like with Japanese locale:

[image]

They're both called FixedSys, but there's obviously a difference. What's the second one actually called, and where is it located in Win7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some historical information from
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixedsys) :

> It is the oldest font in Windows, and was the system font in Windows 1.0 and 2.0, where it was simply named "System". For Windows 3.x, the system font was changed to a proportional sans-serif font named System, but Fixedsys remained the default font in Notepad.

The article [Windows 7: Fixedsys as Console Font](https://codeyarns.com/2010/12/10/windows-7-fixedsys-as-console-font/)
has this:

> There is no font file named fixedsys.*. Fixedsys is a font name mapped to several old raster fonts with the name pattern `*fix*.fon` found in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` directory. These fonts are aimed at different old terminals like VGA, CVGA and others. On Windows 7, these fonts are:

```
8514fix.fon
8514fixe.fon
8514fixg.fon
8514fixr.fon
8514fixt.fon
c8514fix.fon
cvgafix.fon
h8514fix.fon
hvgafix.fon
j8514fix.fon
jvgafix.fon
s8514fix.fon
svgafix.fon
vgafix.fon
vgafixe.fon
vgafixg.fon
vgafixr.fon
vgafixt.fon
```

---

Some fonts in Windows are rather aliases that depend on the locale.

Changing the locale is done in two places that I detail below.
I don't know if they will help in your case, but you could give
them a try.

For both methods, go to Control Panel > Region, then click on Administrative tab.

[image]

**Set the language for non-Unicode programs**

Click the button *Change system locale*.
In the dialog, select your locale.
This is not the Windows locale, just the language locale for non-Unicode programs.
You will need to reboot to apply.

Note: the change of the language used for non-Unicode programs gets applied to ALL non-Unicode apps and files. Therefore, if you need to run another non-Unicode app which uses a different character set, you need to change the non-Unicode program language again.

**Set international settings**

Click the "Copy settings..." button, and you should see a dialog similar to this:

[image]

Set one or both options at the bottom of the dialog, and click OK to copy
the language settings from the current user account to the system account.
Copying non-Japanese language settings to the system account should change the
font mapping.

**Warning** : I suggest creating a system restore point before starting.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that. I'm not necessarily trying to change the font though. I'm just wondering what the Japanese "version" of FixedSys is. It must be a named font that exists somewhere on the computer.

Comment: I found the information and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check all of them, but it looks like the one I wanted was **jvgafix.fon**